# Remove .php from single file with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I know there are hundreads of these questions, and i've nearly went through each one, copied their code and put my link in, but it still redirects to 404. I am having a mind blank right now. I want to make example.com/web load example.com/web.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^web$ /web.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

I figured out my problem. I don't know why, but I added

```
Options -MultiViews
```

above the RewriteEngine On and it loads the page fine now with the answer below.

Comment: This rule works for me. But try Mr. Alien's answer below to account for a possible trailing slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below rule instead...

```
RewriteRule ^web/?$ web.php  [NC]
```

Also this rule is optional for the slash at the end...so it won't throw a 404 if you have URL like

```
http://www.domain.com/web
```

OR

```
http://www.domain.com/web/
```

Comment: Loaded example.com/web and /web/ and still 404's

Comment: I have, several times. Just did again. Still nothing. If I put a `RewriteRule ^something.php$ index.php` and navigate to something.php it loads the index so I know it's loading the `.htaccess`

Comment: @DevynShoe Whats your default directory file name? default.php or index.php or what? Cuz I will give you a rule, which will say that is your htaccess working or not

Comment: index.php -- I have all the files in the root folder, and folders for css, js, etc

Comment: @DevynShoe Use this `DirectoryIndex web.php` at the very top of htaccess, above rewrite engine on line, now if you are on local, just type local/dir_name/ no page name here and see, does it load the web.php by default?

Comment: Going to example.com now loads the web.php page.